# i need to copy a Wordpress Web content to another with different templates

Tags: wordpress, templates, copy

i need to copy some pages from a site to another. I got to use different templates in the different Wordpress installations...  i tried, but some content or style is missing...

Example:

I need to copy this: http://iplido.org.ar/agenda 
 
In this page: http://iplido.org.ar/web/agenda

What can i do? I tried to copy the php files, even some function.php code, but nothing works :(

Comment: you need to copy its the database. But its on the same server so you could just point to the same database

Comment: I got no problem with the content, for example, the posts. My problem is with the style and another kind of content, like the map in here: 
http://iplido.org.ar/delegaciones/
http://iplido.org.ar/web/delegaciones/

Answer (score 0):

To copy the style you need the same theme that is located in wordpress_dir/wp-content/themes/nameofyourtheme.

Copy it to the new installation and through your admin select it in appareance.